# How to run code in C# MVC application without starting the complete application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

So, let's say I have a complete MVC 5 application and would like to execute just a single method **without starting the application**, which does let's say some calls to the database:

Example:

```
public void Test()
{
   ...
   _dbContext.someCollection.ToList();
   ...
}
```

Is that somehow possible?

Comment: You can have a separate project in the same solution, a console app, that references the same set of other projects. From there, call whatever you want. Would post this as an answer but I am not sure this is what you're up to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will do as suggested,  but I believe it does not answer the question

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do what you have described in the same project. A website is meant to start up and serve web pages. I don't think there's a built in mechanism to stop that, other than throwing an exception on startup. That's what a console or unit test project is for.

Comment: In what context do you like to execute this single method? In a separate process, in the same process as the running application (if it is running)? Describe better what you're trying to achieve. Probably, @WiktorZychla's suggestion is the best approach to take.

Comment: I guess it is indeed the best approach and I already implemented a Console application, which does the trick. Nonetheless, I was curious if there was a build in functionality which allows single method call without complete compilation, but as I think of it right now It is illogical, because there are many dependencies and constraints which need compilation, so it is completely inconvenient and error prompt having such functionality.

Comment: LINQPad (http://www.linqpad.net/) might be worth a look. I find it indispensable for playing around with functionality of my applications before actually making changes.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to create  a Test project and then write a unit test for the controller. [try this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/unit-testing/creating-unit-tests-for-asp-net-mvc-applications-cs)